# How to fake authentication when testing firebase functions online?

Tags: firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write tests for my Firebase Cloud Functions, specifically the HTTPS ones. The app uses a permissions system in which each signed-up user of the app has their own entry in Firestore storing the list of permissions they have, indexed by their uid. When these functions are called from the client, the function checks `context.auth` to determine if the user is authenticated, then uses `context.auth.uid` to find the entry for the user in Firestore and determine if they have permissions to run this function.

I am now trying to write tests for these functions using the online mode, as recommended in [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing). However, there does not seem to be a way (at least in this mode) to control the context.auth.uid or mock it for the test. As a result, it seems like it might be impossible to tests these functions in this mode.

Is there any way to do this I'm missing, or some workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `signInAnonymously` method this can create and use temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with [Firebase anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously). According to [Firebase Test SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#:%7E:text=This%20also%20means%20that%20other%20Google%20SDKs%20used%20in%20your%20functions%20will%20work%20as%20well) online mode means that other Google SDKs used in your function will work as well. 
Install both `firebase-functions-test` and [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), a testing framework, by running the following commands in your functions folder:

```
 npm install --save-dev firebase-functions-test
 npm install --save-dev mocha
```

Make sure to follow [test setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#test_setup) and used the [Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#:%7E:text=Send%20feedback-,Authenticate%20with%20Firebase%20Anonymously,-Using%20JavaScript).

Comment: I don't this fixes my problem, because I don't see how that would let me call wrapped firebase functions from my test code while signed in.

Comment: Have you tried any of the mentioned methods above? Have you received any errors using it?